# Longer \nLeftrightarrow

Tags: symbols, mathjax, relation-symbols

I'm looking for a longer \nLeftrightarrow, usable in MathJax / LaTex-enabled StackExchange websites. I tried the following, and I'm puzzled.

[image: attempts]

Comment: `\not` just overlays a / by a fixed difference roughly half the width of =, we could supply tex code that would work in latex but mathjax would most likely need javascript so be off topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
\mathrel{\mathord{\rlap{\hspace{.55em}\not}}\mathord{\Longleftrightarrow}}
```

which moves the `\not` over a bit, while making the final result be a relation so that it gets the proper spacing.  You could define a macro for it if you need to use it more than once.

Comment: Great! See it at work at the end of this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/206485).

Comment: I have read in the recent documentation of mathjax that is possible to use `\require{centernot}` to have the negation to the center of the symbol. https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/centernot.html. Why  `\require{centernot}` not work? +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano, StackExchange is still using version 2.7.5 of MathJax, and the `centernot` package is only available in version 3.2.0 and above.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting comment. I like MathJaX. Do you kwown a website on line free without a registration to write with it and to see the output? When I will see the version 3.2.0 in SE Community? Best regards from Sicily.

Comment: @Sebastiano, try the [MathJax web demos](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web#processing-user-input) site.  Use the "View Demo" link for one of the input examples.

Comment: @DavideCervone Thank you very much. I thought especially to the WYSIWYG MathJaX editor.